# Match substring with alphanumeric characters (ignoring other substrings) in postgres 11

Tags: regex, postgresql

I have following table in Postres

```
col1
A02BX
A02BX Other drugs for peptic ulcer and gastro-oesophageal reflux disease (GORD); A03AE Serotonin receptor antagonists
```

I would like to fetch a substring which is a combination of alphabets and numbers like 'A02BX'. The desired output is:

```
col1
A02BX
A02BX | A03AE
```

I am unable to find any solution to this. Though I tried fetching alphanumeric string using following pattern. But is matching the whole string.

```
[a-zA-Z0-9]+
```

The output I am getting is the same as initial table:

```
A02BX
A02BX Other drugs for peptic ulcer and gastro-oesophageal reflux disease (GORD); A03AE Serotonin receptor antagonists
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may extract all matches using `REGEXP_MATCHES` and a regex that matches alphanumeric substrings in between word boundaries that contain at least one letter and at least one digit:

```
SELECT REGEXP_MATCHES(
       'A02BX Other drugs for peptic ulcer and gastro-oesophageal reflux disease (GORD); A03AE Serotonin receptor antagonists',
       '\y(?:[A-Z]+\d|\d+[A-Z])[A-Z0-9]*\y',
       'g')
```

See an [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/c47a0/1).

**Details**

- `\y` - a word boundary
- `(?:[A-Z]+\d|\d+[A-Z])` - either 1+ letters and a digit or 1+ digits and then a letter
- `[A-Z0-9]*` -  0 or more letters or digits
- `\y` - a word boundary.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```
select * from t;
                                                         col1                                                          
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 A02BX
 A02BX Other drugs for peptic ulcer and gastro-oesophageal reflux disease (GORD); A03AE Serotonin receptor antagonists
(2 rows)

select col1, regexp_matches(col1, '(\w\d\d\w\w)+', 'g') from t;
                                                         col1                                                          | regexp_matches 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------
 A02BX                                                                                                                 | {A02BX}
 A02BX Other drugs for peptic ulcer and gastro-oesophageal reflux disease (GORD); A03AE Serotonin receptor antagonists | {A02BX}
 A02BX Other drugs for peptic ulcer and gastro-oesophageal reflux disease (GORD); A03AE Serotonin receptor antagonists | {A03AE}
```